# Wildcard in make dependency list

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Hey I'm trying to build some files at the same time with different suffixes. Somehow it seems imposible to do this in one line. My makefile looks as follows:

```
ARCH=ar
ARCHFLAGS=r
F90=gfortran
F90FLAGS=-O2 -Wall
LDFLAGS=-llapack -lblas

SRCF=/Users/pm/bin/src
OBJF=/Users/pm/bin/objs
MODF=/Users/pm/bin/mods
LIBF=/Users/pm/bin/include

SOURCES=a.f b.f90 c.f90
OBJECTS=$(addprefix $(OBJF)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES))))
MODULES=$(addprefix $(MODF)/,*.mod)
TARGET=lib_pm_math_lib.a

$(LIBF)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(ARCH) $(ARCHFLAGS) $@ $(OBJECTS) $(MODULES)

obmod.clean :
    rm $(OBJECTS) $(MODULES)

clean :
    rm $(OBJECTS) $(MODULES) $(LIBF)/$(TARGET)

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJF)/%.o : $(addprefix $(SRCF)/,$(join %.,$(suffix $(SOURCES))))
    $(F90) $(F90FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c $< -o$@ -J$(MODF)

#$(OBJECTS): $(OBJF)/%.o : $(subst .x, ,$(addprefix $(SRCF)/,$(addsuffix .x$(suffix $(SOURCES)),%)))
#   $(F90) $(F90FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c $< -o$@ -J$(MODF)

#$(OBJECTS): $(OBJF)/%.o : $(SRCF)/%.f90
#   $(F90) $(F90FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -J$(MODF)
```

As you can see, I already managed to define my OBJECTS. But I'm not able to creat a construct that does the same for the building part of the object. Of course my first try was to use the join without the extra dot, but this results in only the suffix, for whatever reasons. Substituting the two dots with one dot does this as well. So I'm lost. The lines that I commanded out are another interesting try, and a working version for only .f90 suffixes. Actually I was hoping for something like the following to be working:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJF)/%.o : $(SRCF)/%.*
   $(F90) $(F90FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -J$(MODF)
```

I hope it's not too messy. I posted the whole file since I bet you guy's see other problems which I didn't even think of so far. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're wanting a suffix-based wildcard rule that you can run on multiple file suffixes.  You can only have one wildcard per recipe, so there's no way to do it directly.  You'll need separate rules for each suffix.

The easy solution is to copy-paste one rule and change the suffix.  This can become unmanageable when you start to have a lot of suffixes.  Another option is to create a rule template and use that to dynamically generate your rules for you:

```
# Template for build rules
# Pass a file extension for an argument
define build_rule
$(OBJF)/%.o: $(SRCF)/%.$(1)
    $(F90) $(F90FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c $$< -o$$@ -J$(MODF)
endef

# Generate rules for each selected file extension
FILE_EXTS = f f90
$(foreach ext,$(FILE_EXTS),$(eval $(call build_rule,$(ext))))
```

This will dynamically generate a rule that differs only by the file extension used on the input file.  To support a new file extension, simply add it to the `FILE_EXTS` list.

Note that when make initially parses the recipe template (inside `call`), it will expand variables.  You have to double-up the `$` in the template for anything that you don't want make to expand until the recipe is actually executed (like `$@` or `$<`).

You shouldn't need to do anything special to ensure that only the objects in the `OBJECTS` list are compiled.  Since your default make target only lists `$(OBJECTS)` as a dependency, the files in `$(OBJECTS)` will be the only ones that get built.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Interesting that there is no direct way, but still your solution is quite satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I'd probably just use two rules:

```
$(OBJF)/%.o: $(SRCF)/%.f
    $(F90) $(F90FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c $< -o$@ -J$(MODF)

$(OBJF)/%.o: $(SRCF)/%.f90
    $(F90) $(F90FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c $< -o$@ -J$(MODF)
```

You *could* combine them into one, but it's not really worth the effort.

Comment: Well yes in the easies case this solves the issue. Of course it would be interesting how I can combine them. But what's acutally much more important for me is, how I can specify that only the objects mentioned in the OBJECTS list are compiled. Probably therefore it's necessary to combine both steps.

Comment: @PeMa: You seem to have the wrong idea about how Make works. Suppose there's another source file, `src/d.f90`; Make will not do anything with it when you build `lib_pm_math_lib.a`. What do you want Make to do when you type `make objs/d.o`?

Comment: Yes I already got it. bta made it clear in his (or her) edit. It's my first make file, so I'm not entirely in the make way of thinking.